# Оптимизация: что лучше стек или массив

Tags: delphi, ассемблер

Читал возможно устаревшую литературу по ассемблеру, что лучше всего для скорости работать со стеком push/pop.
Но если работа идет не по Last-In-First-Out (LIFO), а например многократный пробег массива в "хаотичном" или в другом направлениях(FiFo). Через pop стек читать не получится(потеряешь данные), но можно читать посредством прямого обращения к памяти вместо pop:

```
push xxxx
lea rbx, [esp+...]
mov rax, UInt64 ptr [rbx+8]
mov rax, UInt64 ptr [rbx+64]
```

Вопрос Если читать не через LiFo то есть ли преимущество в таком чтении через стек? Ведь можно и напрямую считывать данные из массива, не прибегая к его записи в стек(push/pop а это тоже накладные расходы):

```
type
  TBigData = array of UInt64;

   mov rbx, [Array]
   mov rax, UInt64 ptr [rbx+8]
   mov rax, UInt64 ptr [rbx+64]
```

В обоих случаях нам нужно прочесть данные в разных местах массива/стека

Так понимаю в обоих случаях современные технологии оставляют прочитанные данные в кэшах верхнего уровня и если постоянно читать, писать эти данные, то скорость что с push \ напрямую работа с массивом будет одинаковая?

Возможно еще какие-то нюансы кроме скорости, доступность, блокировки, ресурсы и т.д.

**Добавлено после комментариев:**
Видимо не понятно написан вопрос, есть массив в Дельфи, в нем идут множественные сложные вычисления, поэтому на асм переписывать с ума сойдешь, нужно все делить процедурами/модулями, иначе всё будет слишком не понятно. Зачем тогда асм?
Есть узкие места алгоритма, где происходят долгие вычисления арифметического характера. Даже с моим пару недельным знакомством с асм скорость обработки "узких мест" на асм в **2-10 раз быстрее**, в сравнению с паскаль кодом Дельфи(Build=Release, Optimisation=False)
Эти массивы уже и так определены в Дельфи, и передаются в асм-процедуру, обработай 1,2,3 массива и пару параметров, результат запиши в массив(тоже обычный созданный в Дельфи). А вот что делать в асм вопрос, напрямую обрабатывать массив или через стек? Напомню что обработка идет с многими проходами и не через LiFo

```
type TBigData = array of UInt64;
Var A,C: TBigData;
begin
  //Данные в A где-то заполнены.
  SetLength(C,xxxx);//выделять память пустому массиву
  SQRInf_a(@A, @C, length(A));
end;

procedure Stek(A, C: Pointer; Size: Cardinal);assembler;
asm
  .NOFRAME
  mov r11d, Size

//!!! Загрузка массива (множимое A) в стек
  mov rax, [A]
  mov rcx, r11
 @N://Начала цикла
  mov r10, UInt64 ptr [rax]//массив A
  add rax, 8//массив A
  push r10
  loop @N//конец цикла

//Здесь будут вычисления и out данные пойдут в массив [C]
end;
```

тот же самый алгоритм, но без пробега по стеку, отличие работа напрямую с массивом [A] и нет загрузки массива в стек

```
procedure Stek(A, C: Pointer; Size: Cardinal);assembler;
asm
  .NOFRAME
  mov r11d, Size
  mov rax, [A]

//Здесь будут вычисления и out данные пойдут в массив [C]
end;
```

Анализ по скорости, например сделал простую функцию по вычислению в столбик квадрата большого числа(длинная арифметика число в 16000 байтов или 2000 элементов-UInt64 массива) **алгоритм прямой работы с массивом ровно в два раза быстрее чем со стеком**. Понятно почему, нет лишней загрузки в стек, и видимо это значит что после первого же пробега по массиву в RAM он сохраняется в кэше процессора и скорость доступа будет наибыстрейшая что возможна. Мерил в "попугаях" тиках(импульсах счетчика, тактов) процессора: QueryPerformanceCounter.

Comment: `лучше всего для скорости работать со стеком push/pop` В каком контексте и с чем сравнение? Массив - всего лишь адрес. В стеке он лежит физически или в куче - большой разницы нет.

Comment: Преимущества по скорости конечно нет, потому как и стек и массив лежат в оперативной памяти абсолютно одинаково. Единственное отличие стека "обычный способ доступа", вот те самые push/pop. У стека есть единственное "преимущество" из за которого его используют в подобных функциях языки высокого уровня. В нем удобно хранить _локальные переменные_. Если вам надо, что бы функция могла вызывать сама себя и у каждой работающей "копии" был собственный массив, то его можно держать в стеке (если он не большой, конечно)

Comment: А еще, раз речь про оптимизацию, `TBigData = array of UInt64` задействует внутренний менеджер памяти языка, который выполняет гораздо больше операций, чем обычный `mov bp, sp / sub sp, X` для резервирования места в стеке. Так что это явно медленнее. Но с другой стороны, стек сильно ограничен размерами и хранить в нем "Big Data" явно не следует.

Comment: @задействует внутренний менеджер памяти язык@ можно поподробнее. ничего не понял ;(

Comment: `можно поподробнее` -  Почитайте про динамические массивы

Comment: Какова реальная задача?

Comment: реальная задача повторить Дельфи, начать учить асм, длинная арифметика, числа любой длины и абсолютной точности. Написание калькулятора(делить. умножить, сложить, вычесть, возвести в квадрат, тоже самое но модульная арифметика) после этого работа с большими простыми числами, как минимум уровня RSA ключей (2048бит++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разницы в записи/чтении нет, `pop` и `push` работают с той же скоростью, что и `mov`. Конечно они ещё одновременно производят декремент/инкремент указателя, который в случае `mov` придётся делать отдельно, но для этого есть более удобные *цепочечные инструкции* `lods` и `stos` (которые, в отличие от `pop`/`push`, могут читать/записывать в обоих направлениях).

Стоит обратить внимание на *SIMD инструкции (MMX, SSE, AVX)* - с их помощью можно добиться наибольшей оптимизации, т. к. они позволяют параллельно обрабатывать сразу несколько элементов массива за одну операцию. Не уверен, поддерживается ли в Delphi набор инструкций *AVX*, но  поддержка *MMX* и *SSE* там точно есть.

---

В качестве дополнения: `pop`/`push` вовсе не привязаны к стеку, они привязаны к регистру `rsp`, а в него можно загрузить любой указатель, в том числе и указатель на массив:

```
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp //сохраняем rsp (чтобы не потерять указатель стека)
mov rsp, A //загружаем в rsp указатель на массив

//теперь тут можно читать массив используя pop

mov rsp, rbp //возвращаем в rsp указатель стека
pop rbp
```

Answer (score 0):

С массивом быстрее и памяти меньше надо. Вы ведь при использовании стека сначала массив в стек копируете.